# Autofac specify web.config to use

Tags: testing, web-config, autofac

For testing purposes I need to use a .net 7 test project to instantiate a legacy .net 4.6 class that uses Autofac for the IOC.
I appreciate this may not be possible, but how can I specify the `web.config` file to use for the project under test when setting up the IOC container?
I need to use a separate appsettings.json file for the test projects

```
using Autofac;
public class myClass()
{
    public void myMethod()
    {
        ContainerBuilder builder = new Autofac.ContainerBuilder();
                
        builder.RegisterType<Ping>().As<IPing>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<Pong>().As<IPong>().SingleInstance();
            ...
        /// what is the Autofac equivalent of the method LoadConfigFromFile?
        builder.LoadConfigFromFile($"{mypath}\\web.config");
        
        IContainer container = builder.Build()
        
        var pong = container.Resolve <IPong>()
        
    }
}
```

##### web.config

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="initalcatalog=myServer datasource = TableTennis ..... "providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    
</connectionStrings>

   ...


</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

**MASSIVE DISCLAIMER**: [Autofac hasn't supported web.config based configuration since 2016](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/xml.html) when Autofac.Configuration v4.0 was released. There may or may not be a good solution here. [The legacy pre-4.0 docs are still there](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/xml.html#configuring-with-application-configuration-legacy-pre-4-0) but you're well beyond support.

With all that said... if you [go back in time and look at the source for 3.3.0](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Configuration/tree/v3.3.0) you'll see that [`ConfigurationSettingsReader` has a constructor that takes a file path](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Configuration/blob/72dee70a89d1012fa890840bde7a65ebb1a0b744/src/Autofac.Configuration/ConfigurationSettingsReader.cs#L96) so that seems like the way to go.

The example in the docs shows that you'd usually do this:

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterModule(new ConfigurationSettingsReader("mycomponents"));
```

To provide a specific file, then, it'd be:

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterModule(new ConfigurationSettingsReader("mycomponents", "path/to/my/web.config"));
```

**I haven't tried this.** But it looks like that should do what you want.